# Unhandled "error" event. (TypeError: Cannot read property 'header' of null)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme

Not really sure how to fix the following error

Trying to create an unit test - I already defined all this.props but when I run it, this error keeps showing up.

**Using React JS -  JEST/ ENZYME**

here is part of the code:

```
renderHeaders = () => {
let headersJSON = this.extractDataFromXML({ firstKey: 'header', xml: 
 this.props.tableData.headers })
return headersJSON.header.map((headerName, idx) => {
  return (
    <th name={headerName['_']}>{headerName['_']}</th>
  )
})
}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example producing there poblem.
Your example doesn't contain `.header`, which is what causes the error.

Comment: return headersJSON.header.map((headerName, idx) = this is the only place where it contains .header